# Aurelia authentication: How to obtain the user id

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-auth

I am using the [aurelia-auth](https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth) library in a new project.
Everything seems to be correct so far, but I am unable to show the user information on the navigation bar.

The library provides some functions that seems to provide such information, like `getTokenPayload()`. I am trying to access to this information in order to show the user id or the user name in the navigation bar.

I have seen that other properties (such as `isAuthenticated()`) are being accessed this way:

`nav-bar.html:`

```
<ul if.bind="isAuthenticated" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="/#/logout">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

`nav-bar.js:`

```
export class NavBar {
  ...
  get isAuthenticated() {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated();
  };
```

I am unable to figure out how could I display on the navigation bar the user Id (obtained through the `getTokenPayload()` function) once the user has been authenticated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `getTokenPayload` in the `attached` callback for `NavBar` (you would probably want to call `isAuthenticated` to first check if the user is authenticated). Set a property on your `NavBar` VM to the token payload and then use databinding to bind to the user ID property.

Then, set up an `EventAggregator` subscription in the `NavBar` attached callback to subscribe to the proper `auth` event (probably `'auth:authenticate'`) and call `getTokenPayload` in the callback for that subscription and then set the VM property. This will make sure the property gets updated if the auth information changes.

You're going to want to subscribe to the `'auth:logout'` event and unset the VM property you set above. Set this subscription up in the `attached` callback as well.

Finally, make sure to dispose of these subscriptions in the `detached` callback of the `NavBar` VM.

Comment: It would be very useful to have a full working example. There are many aspects involved in the authorization workflow and I find complicated to deal with that, even using some great libraries such as the one from SpoonX (https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-authentication)